# setup wing ide for remote debugging

Tags: python, debugging, remote-debugging, wing-ide

I have wing-ide installed on my local machine.
And when I run `python wingdbstub.py` from local it connects to IDE.

But it's not working for remote debugging described [here](https://wingware.com/doc/debug/installing-debugger-core), 
[ssh_tunelling](https://wingware.com/doc/debug/ssh-tunnels)

How do I fix/(test) it ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info on how it fails?  For example, set kLogFile in wingdbstub.py and email the output to support@wingware.com.  I'm unclear on what you show above (where it came from, etc) and don't know if it's relevant.

Comment: it not fails, it's just not connects from remote to local.

Comment: @Wingware, I want to be able to debug sample python script on my vps. I have prepared and copied files to remote server like on first screen. And the last screenshot is the iptables output.

Comment: My directory located at `/root/project/dbg` so my `WING_HOME="/root/project/dbg"` in `wingdbstub.py`. Is that correct?

Comment: For failure of wingdbstub.py to connect back to the IDE, set kLogFile in wingdbstub.py and send us the output (to support@wingware.com).  The reverse ssh tunnel should bypass ip tables so I don't think that's relevant unless the remote host is disallowing listening on port 50005 there, which it may but I think then ssh would print an error message.  Adding -v to the ssh command makes it verbose, which may help if the error is at that level.

Comment: Also, is the remote host the same architecture and OS as the host you copied the debugger files from?  The debugger contains an extension module so those need to match.  It's generally easier to install Wing on the remote machine from the installer.  WINGHOME (not WING_HOME as you wrote above) should be set to the install location in that case (usually /usr/lib/wingide5 on Linux).  If using what you copied and show above I think you've got the right value for WINGHOME.